# How can i downgrade GCC 4.7.2?

Tags: lubuntu, gcc, g++

i want to downgrade GCC and G++ 4.7.2 to some older versions, 4.0 perhaps. Any assistance? I'm using Lubuntu ATM.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't know why BlueBaron might want to do that, but I would do that if I had an important codebase that had been compiled with GCC 4.0 and subject to a lot of testing. On a previous job, I versioned the GCC toolchain. If we checked out a baseline from six months ago, its makefiles would point to the compiler which was used six months ago.

Comment: There are good reasons not to use the latest, shiniest release of GCC, such as that it's a fast moving target with poor QA.

Answer (score 2):

> You can install 4.4, 4.6, 4.7

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.
gcc-4.4                               gcc-4.6-plugin-dev                    gcc-4.7-locales
gcc-4.4-base                          gcc-4.6-source                        gcc-4.7-multilib
gcc-4.4-doc                           gcc-4.7                               gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi
gcc-4.4-locales                       gcc-4.7-aarch64-linux-gnu             gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
gcc-4.4-multilib                      gcc-4.7-aarch64-linux-gnu-base        gcc-4.7- multilib-powerpc-linux-gnu
gcc-4.4-source                        gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi             gcc-4.7-plugin-dev
gcc-4.6                               gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi-base        gcc-4.7-powerpc-linux-gnu
gcc-4.6-base                          gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf           gcc-4.7-powerpc-linux-gnu-base
gcc-4.6-doc                           gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base      gcc-4.7-source
gcc-4.6-locales                       gcc-4.7-base                          
gcc-4.6-multilib                      gcc-4.7-doc
```

You need to install **base** package for example

```
  sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4-base
```

Comment: Can you get 4.0 this way?

Comment: nope ...only starting from 4.4

Comment: do this sudo apt-get install gcc  then press " Tab " key twice